# String comparison using '==' or '===' vs. 'strcmp()'

Tags: php

It seems that PHP's `===` operator is case sensitive. So is there a reason to use `strcmp()`?

Is it safe to do something like the following?

```
if ($password === $password2) { ... }
```

Comment: What's case-sensitivity have to do with `strcmp`?

Comment: @KennyTM: `strcmp` is case-sensitive.  In some languages, like VB, string comparison may not be, and thus would return a different result.  This isn't the case in PHP, though.

Comment: @cHao: `=` in VB is case-sensitive, also the language is not.

Comment: @jiewmeng:  Ideally, you should be hashing your password and comparing hashes.  Aside from that, your code should be fine.

Comment: @jie: You may want to use `===` instead of `==` because `'0XAB' == '0xab'` is true.

Comment: @KennyTM: In VB, `Option Compare Text` (which used to be very commonly used; dunno whether it is anymore) makes string comparisons case insensitive.

Comment: @cHao: oh yes thats just an example

Comment: to use === instead of == is important, because comparing any string to 0 with == will return true which is obviously false...

Comment: @Kenny Also '0xAB' == '171'

Comment: What is going on in this thread? Why are all answers saying "Use === instead of ==", when OP never asked about that? They used `==` in the title, but all those answers should be comments... I came here looking for the usage of `strcmp`, not for the reasons of using `===`.

Answer (score 349, accepted):

The reason to use it is because [`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp)

> returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

`===` only returns `true` or `false`, it doesn't tell you which is the "greater" string.

Comment: icic tho in my current case, i dont need to know which string is greater :)

Comment: strcmp with matching strings took 0.207852 seconds strcmp with non-matching strings took 0.215276 seconds === with matching strings took 0.067122 seconds === with non-matching strings took 0.057305 seconds  http://snipplr.com/view/758/

Comment: The other usage for strcmp it shows the sorting. To be more clear about sorting. strcmp() returns <0 if string1 sorts before string2, >0 if string2 sorts before string1 or 0 if they are the same. For example 
$string_first = "aabo";
$string_second = "aaao";
echo $n = strcmp($string_first,$string_second);

will return greater than zero, as aaao is sorting before aabo.

Comment: Why does this answer get the most upvotes? I'm downvoting because although it's the answer that this question deserves but not the 'right' answer. Right answer should be 'Use ===' as a lot of people already said in other answers.

Comment: PHP... Does this actually compare the characters or just the number?!

Comment: @onur güngör Actually, this *does* answers the op's question, which is `So is there any reason to use strcmp() ?`, while Postfuturist's answer doesn't.

Oh, hell... no one answer seemed to compile at once the **use** of `strcmp()`, the **performance** of `===`, and the *bad reliability* of `==` for string comparisons...  so I added mine to the list.

Comment: @Balmipour yes and no, the author is implying string comparison, == only does string comparison on certain occasions, e.g. "00123" == "123", is true, but is WRONG for string comparison.

Comment: @Rahly I must have missed that part, you're right.  On the other hand, I didn't add [***my* answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986959/2472389) without reason ;).  Having to read all the page to get decent informations (and finding no answer with all at once !) was quite disappointing, considering the basic question we are facing.

Comment: @user503853 On my machine it's 1.366 vs 0.97. So the difference is not that significant anymore.

Answer (score 227):

You should never use `==` for string comparison. `===` is OK.

```
$something = 0;
echo ('password123' == $something) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Just run the above code and you'll see why.

```
$something = 0;
echo ('password123' === $something) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Now, that's a little better.

Comment: == isn't just a problem for differing types. It will sometimes give unexpected results even if both sides are a string. Try '1e3' == '1000'

Comment: how does 0 == 'password123' ?

Comment: @AndyLobel PHP coerces 'password123' to a number using it's odd loose comparison rules since the other operand is a number, that string, like most, coerces to the number 0, and PHP returns true for the comparison.

Comment: A quick var_dump((int)'password123'); helped me fully understand why this happened...**embarrassed**...I really like the === operator

Comment: this is beacuse using '==' if one of the two operands is castable to number, php casts both the operands to numbers, and more, if a not number string is casted to number, it takes value zero, resulting equals to zero, so the result of the comparison with simple '==' can something unwanted

Comment: Its the same even if neither is a int type.  e.g. "00123" == "123", so even though they are BOTH strings, the operator coerses both into a number.

Comment: Perhaps explain the why in your answer? Stack Overflow is not a school.

Comment: Hi, @PeterMortensen I was surprised to get an email notification of your comment on my *11 year old* stackoverflow response. Gave me a good laugh. There's an edit button, so you can improve the response if you care, which you seem to. Stack Overflow is not a school, indeed.

Comment: PHP 8.1 results (see it in action) --> https://onlinephp.io/c/88c28

Answer (score 106):

Don't use `==` in PHP. It will not do what you expect. Even if you are comparing strings to strings, PHP will implicitly cast them to floats and do a numerical comparison if they appear numerical.

For example `'1e3' == '1000'` returns true. You should use `===` instead.

Comment: @Roman yes but a lot of PHP programmers don't know they have to do that. Hence the warning.

Comment: @Antimony So why not tell them what they *should* do in your answer?

Answer (score 44):

Well...according to this [PHP bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64069), you can even get [0wned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owned_(slang)).

```
<?php
    $pass = isset($_GET['pass']) ? $_GET['pass'] : '';
    // Query /?pass[]= will authorize user
    //strcmp and strcasecmp both are prone to this hack
    if ( strcasecmp( $pass, '123456' ) == 0 ){
      echo 'You successfully logged in.';
    }
 ?>
```

It gives you a warning, but still bypass the comparison.
You should be doing `===` as @postfuturist suggested.

Comment: Wow +1. Quote from the link: "It is established behavior for function that receive the wrong type of argument(s) to return null". That's amazing considering the manual just says this: "Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal". Null is not mentioned as a possibility, yet on pages such as the substr man page it is mentioned. *sigh*

Comment: But does the same happens when the form method is post ...?

Comment: @NikhilGeorge It does, the function in question here is strcmp. It doesn't matter which inputs are being compared against.

Comment: While the bug report says it was fine to return null, this is incorrect. All official PHP releases from PHP 4.3 to PHP 7.3 do not return null from these functions. I suspect it may've been an alpha or beta release, and regardless of the bug being closed is invalid, it was fixed. See https://3v4l.org/Zq8tM for details, which show that it does affect HHVM 3.11 - 3.19.

Answer (score 35):

Always remember, when comparing strings, you should use the [`===`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator (strict comparison) and *not* `==` operator (loose comparison).

Comment: Actually, I think it's safe to say that you should use `===` when comparing *anything*.

Answer (score 27):

> Summing up all answers:

- `==` is a **bad idea** for string comparisons.

   It will give you "surprising" results in many cases.  Don't trust it.
- `===` is fine, and will give you the best performance.
- `strcmp()` should be used if you need to determine which string is "greater", typically for sorting operations.

Answer (score 21):

Using `==` might be dangerous.

Note, that it would cast the variable to another data type if the two differs.

Examples:

- `echo (1 == '1') ? 'true' : 'false';`
- `echo (1 == true) ? 'true' : 'false';`

As you can see, these two are from different types, but the result is `true`, which might not be what your code will expect.

Using `===`, however, is recommended as test shows that it's a bit faster than `strcmp()` and its case-insensitive alternative `strcasecmp()`.

Quick googling yells this speed comparison: http://snipplr.com/view/758/

Comment: Sometimes it casts them to a different type even if they already have the same type.

Comment: even when comparing two strings that represented an integer like `"012" == "12"` php changed the type of both strings to integer `12 == 12` and then returned `true`.

Comment: @GoTo: Didn't that change in some later PHP version?

Comment: @PeterMortensen No idea. Currently I don't write PHP.

Answer (score 14):

`strcmp()` and `===` are both case sensitive, but `===` is much faster.

Sample code: *[Speed Test: strcmp vs ===](http://snipplr.com/view/758/)*

Answer (score 6):

strcmp will return different values based on the environment it is running in (Linux/Windows)!

The reason is the that it has a bug as the bug report says - *[Bug #53999strcmp() doesn't always return -1, 0, or 1](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53999)*

Comment: It will always return 0 if the strings are equal, though. +1 for being careful about caring about any other value than 0 though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `strcmp()` if you wish to order/compare strings [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). If you just wish to check for equality then `==` is just fine.

Comment: Like in [usort](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).  In fact, it's pretty much made for sorting.

Comment: @Charles Thanks.  Wikipedia made my eyes glaze over.

Comment: To be more clear about sorting. strcmp() returns <0 if string1 sorts before string2, >0 if string2 sorts before string1 or 0 if they are the same. For example 
$string_first = "aabo";
$string_second = "aaao";
echo $n = strcmp($string_first,$string_second);

will return greater than zero, as aaao is sorting before aabo.

Comment: @postfuturist I'm sure it's a typo and they meant `===`.

Answer (score 4):

Also, the function can help in sorting. To be more clear about sorting. strcmp() returns less than 0 if string1 sorts before string2, greater than 0 if string2 sorts before string1 or 0 if they are the same. For example

```
$first_string = "aabo";
$second_string = "aaao";
echo $n = strcmp($first_string, $second_string);
```

The function will return greater than zero, as *aaao* is sorting before *aabo*.

Answer (score 1):

`if ($password === $password2) { ... }` is not a safe thing to do when comparing passwords or password hashes where one of the inputs is user controlled.
In that case it creates a timing oracle allowing an attacker to derive the actual password hash from execution time differences.
Use `if (hash_equals($password, $password2)) { ... }` instead, because [hash_equals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php) performs "timing attack safe string comparison".

Comment: What is *"timing oracle"*? *[Padding oracle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack)*? Or something else? Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59723436/edit) some references? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: A timing oracle attack is comparing the execution times of the same operation done with different inputs. $a === $b completes as soon as difference is detected, while hash_equals explicitly keeps comparing the remainder even though the result is already known. So for the latter, execution time is independent of original input when comparing hashes (which always have the same length regardless of input).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, instead of using alphabetical sorting, use the **ASCII** value of the character to make the comparison.

Lowercase letters have a higher **ASCII** value than capitals. It's better to use the identity operator **===** to make this sort of comparison. **strcmp()** is a function to perform binary safe string comparisons. It takes two strings as arguments and returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal. There is also a *case-insensitive* version named **strcasecmp()** that first converts strings to lowercase and then compares them.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, for comparing two strings, use [`collator_compare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/collator.compare.php) instead. It works with Unicode and it's more flexible than `strcmp` or `strcasecmp`. Those two legacy functions give strange results for non-trivial inputs and the documentation is misleading on them returning straightforward values like -1, 0, or 1.

Here is the first example from the documentation for `collator_compare`:

```php
<?php
$s1 = 'Hello';
$s2 = 'hello';

$coll = collator_create( 'en_US' );
$res  = collator_compare( $coll, $s1, $s2 );

if ($res === false) {
    echo collator_get_error_message( $coll );
} else if( $res > 0 ) {
    echo "s1 is greater than s2\n";
} else if( $res < 0 ) {
    echo "s1 is less than s2\n";
} else {
    echo "s1 is equal to s2\n";
}
?>
```

Note: the PHP `intl` extension is required.