# How to count the number of certain string inside array?

Tags: php, arrays

Hey!
I am trying to count the number of times a certain string exists inside an array.  I have tried this..
My array:

```
$test = array('correct','correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct');

in_array('correct',$test); // only gives me true
```

I thought about count(); but that only returns the count of items...So how can count for how many "correct" strings are in that array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `preg_grep` ?

```
$count = count(preg_grep('/^correct$/', $test));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($test as $t)
    if ( strcmp($t, "correct") == 0)
         $count++;
```

Comment: It's the first time I see someone using `strcmp` to compare two string in PHP! (BTW, I think that here, == runs way faster)

Comment: Force of habit I guess. Of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/php-string-comparison-vs-strcmp

Comment: Sure, it might be useful, but it's not so often that you need to find the greatest of two string (I never had to)! ^^
About speed: http://snipplr.com/view/758/speed-test-strcmp-vs-/

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine [`count`](http://php.net/count) and [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) for this:

```
$count = count(array_filter($test, function($val) {
    return $val === 'correct';
}));
```

Note that the function syntax supports PHP >=5.3 only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;

foreach ($test as $testvalue) {
if ($testvalue == "correct") { $count++; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count_instances($haystack, $needle){
  $count = 0;
  foreach($haystack as $i)
    if($needle == $i)
      $count++;
  return $count;
}
```