# PHP strcmp not giving correct output

Tags: php, strcmp

> I am comparing two string by `strcmp(1,2)` and i am getting "-1 " insted of 1 my code is below

```
  <?php
    echo strcmp(1,2);
   ?>
```

output:-1

[image]

please let me know why i am getting -1 for false and how to handle it ?

Comment: @Jack ya i know it sir, and so i thought output will be false "1" but its -1

Comment: If the first argument is less than the second, it will return a negative number.

Comment: Why are you using a string comparison function to compare numbers? If you want to know if 22 is less than 9 -> `if (22 < 9) { ... }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/php-string-comparison-vs-strcmp

Comment: @trante thank you .. this link is really helpful ... again thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 is less than 2, strcmp is defined as returning:

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than
>   str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Thus the behaviour is expected.

---

Note the following caveat:

> If you rely on strcmp for safe string comparisons, both parameters
>   must be strings, the result is otherwise extremely unpredictable. For
>   instance you may get an unexpected 0, or return values of NULL, -2, 2,
>   3 and -3.

From a comment on the documentation page for [`strcmp`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#108563).

---

PHP is full of this sort of unexpected behaviour. In your situation, I would ensure both arguments were cast as strings to avoid any confusion:

```
$first = 1;
$second = 2;
echo strcmp((string)$first, (string)$second);
```

Comment: +1 That's interesting behaviour, what with the -2 and -3. Amazing :)

Comment: @Jack I'm fairly certain it implicity casts to a string.  What could be happening with some of the odd numeric ones is that the number is too large to be represented so it can't be converted properly to a number (int/float) to then be converted to a string.  Edit: actually, after looking at the list closer, those are some weird outcomes.  No telling how it's implemented >.<

Comment: @Corbin I'm talking about this: `strcmp(NULL, "foo") => -3` :) The large numeric ones are easy to explain, because they're `double` first before being converted to string, losing precision.

Comment: @Jack (string) null === ""; strcmp("", "foo") === -3.  So it's not shocking by any means, but it is indeed interesting I suppose (since I'm not quite sure where 3 comes from -- based on a tiny bit of experimenting, fooo returns -4, so I think the behavior might be to return the strlen of the second string if the first is empty).

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in an int, it is casted to a string as evidenced by:

```
var_dump(strcmp('1', 2)); //-1
```

The reason it's -1 is because the most widely used implementation of strcmp finds the first non-equal character and returns the difference.

In other words, it's essentially '1' - '2' which is 49 - 50 (ASCII codes for '1' and '2').

49-50 is -1.

Edit: Not strictly relevant, but out of curiosity, did some digging.  This is by no means guaranteed behavior in the future, but from PHP 5.4:

```
ZEND_FUNCTION(strcmp)
{
    char *s1, *s2;
    int s1_len, s2_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "ss", &s1, &s1_len, &s2, &s2_len) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    RETURN_LONG(zend_binary_strcmp(s1, s1_len, s2, s2_len));
}


ZEND_API int zend_binary_strcmp(const char *s1, uint len1, const char *s2, uint len2) /* {{{ */
{
    int retval;

    if (s1 == s2) {
        return 0;
    }
    retval = memcmp(s1, s2, MIN(len1, len2));
    if (!retval) {
        return (len1 - len2);
    } else {
        return retval;
    }
}
```

It does indeed cast to a string.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get `false`.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php).

> Return Values
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than
>   str2, and 0 if they are equal.