# PHP If / else user exists on database set variable to 0 or 1

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have this code to check if user exists in database. I want to assign `$account` to `1` if it exits, and `0` if it doesn't. I thought this code would work but its constantly setting `$account` to `0` so I think im missing a trick. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");

 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

$sql="SELECT user_name FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['user_name'] == '$user_name'){
$account = 1;
}else{
        $account = 0;}
```

Thanks

Comment: when you compare strings it's better practice to use [strcomp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) as follows: `if(strcomp($row['user_name'], $user_name) == 0)`

Comment: @alfasin: `===` would also be sufficient and more readable in this case ([related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/php-string-comparison-vs-strcmp)).

Comment: @jmdeldin you're absolutely right!

Comment: @alfasin, best practise, really?  I disagree, @jmdeldin says `===` is a much better choice since it's more readable.

Comment: @therefromhere and did you see what I replied ? now, if you quote me please try to be accurate: I said "better practice" not "best", `strcomp` preforms a binary safe string comparison which is more reliable than "==". Now, was I wrong ?

Comment: @alfasin sorry, I miss-read better as best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put variables in a string if you use single quotes `'` (plus it's not necessary!). Below rectifies that issue, and shortens your if/else statement into a one-liner.

```
$account = $row['user_name']==$user_name ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You can put variables inside a string, however the wrapping quotations would have to be double in order for the variable to be interpolated.

Comment: Yes, that's why I stated ".. if you use single quotes" - but either quotes are pointless in this instance.

Comment: You could also cast the result as an int: `(int) ($row['user_name'] == $user_name);` However, if you do rely on PHP's idea of equality with `==` or `if ($account)`, then explicitly converting a boolean to an int isn't needed (e.g., `true == '1'`).

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be done a better way:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");

 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

$account = (int)mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE user_name='$user_name'");
```

That should store the correct value in account, i.e. 1 if the user is found and 0 if not.

Answer (score 1):

You're query is returning multiple rows, and you are doing the comparison with the first row.  you need to do something like the follwing to specify a single user (see sql statement change):

```
$sql="SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='".$user_name."' ";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['user_name'] == '$user_name'){
$account = 1;
}else{
        $account = 0;}
```

also, to iterate over rows, you can see this example from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if ($row['user_name'] == '$user_name'){
```

to:

```
if ($row['user_name'] == $user_name){
```

Single quotes signifies a string. So, by putting your variable between the single quotes, you're trying to match `$row['user_name']` to `$user_name` (not string inside the $user_name variable - but STRING "$user_name").

Double quotes also signifies a string, but you can put your variable between double quotes and `$row['user_name']` will match to `$user_name` (a string inside the variable).

So, the following two examples are correct, and yours isn't:

```
if ($row['user_name'] == $user_name){
if ($row['user_name'] == "$user_name"){
```