# header() is not redirecting to the page in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following PHP **printExam.php** page:

```
    <?php   
    $logins = array(
        'user' => 'pass',
        'user1' => 'pass1',
        'user2' => 'pass2',
        'user3' => 'pass3',
        'user4' => 'pass4'
    );

    // Clean up the input values 
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {  
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]); 

        $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key])); 
    }

    /******************************************************************************/
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

          $user = isset($_POST['user']) ? strtolower($_POST['user']) : '';
          $pass = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';
          $report = $_POST['typereport'];

          if ((!array_key_exists($user, $logins))||($logins[$user] != $pass)) {
             showForm("Wrong Username/Password");
             exit();     
          }
          else {
    if ($report == "Clinical") {    
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
CLINICAL PAGE
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
    elseif ($report == "Annual Education") {
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
ANNUAL EDUCATION PAGE
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
          }
       } else {
          showForm();
          exit();
       }

    function showForm($error=""){
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Certificate Printing :: Login</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <Script>
    $(function() {
      $("#user").focus();
    });
    </Script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form id="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd">
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <fieldset id="inputs">
            <input id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username" autofocus="" required="" type="text">   
            <input id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="radio" name="typereport" id="cbox" value="Clinical" checked="yes" /> Clinical 
            <input type="radio" name="typereport" id="cbox" value="Annual Education" /> Annual Education
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" type="submit">
        </fieldset>
        <div class="caption"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>
```

For **printCert.php** and **printCertHR.php**, the very first line is:

```
<?php require_once('printExam.php'); ?>
```

What it is suppose to do is call the printExam.php page each time the user visits either pages. If the username AND password matches and depending on the selection, whether it's clinical or annual education, it should take the user to the correct page. I know the form is working correctly, because if I enter wrong username/password it shows me the error but once correct, it doesnt redirect. Any idea how to resolve it?

**Please Note**: the username/password is simplified for the example only!

Comment: does your script reach the expected `if` statement? can you `echo` something from there? what is the value of `$report` just right before the `if`? maybe you better to comment out that `exit;` also ...

Comment: not relevant to this question, but you cannot have duplicate IDs on a DOM element. your `id="cbox"` radio buttons cannot share the same id.

Comment: If no redirection is happening, then what does the screen displays? And yeah, as the Mahdi suggested, why not print some messages and see if it has reached that point?

Comment: I edited my question above to reflect your request.

Comment: I get this error now: `printcert.php
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/web/i/interfaithmedical.com/htdocs/checksite/printExam.php:45) in /home/web/i/interfaithmedical.com/htdocs/checksite/printExam.php on line 46`

Comment: Before submit condition code I would add `echo '<br><pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre><br>';` to check submitted data

Comment: 'Headers already sent' Is because of the blank lines as I mention in my answer

Comment: I fixed it and the same error

Comment: I think it's the `header();` that's failing because I took out that line and just added an `echo` and it prints out in the correct condition.

Comment: **"You can't have your cake and eat it too"**. Which translated in PHP means, you can't have an `echo` with a `header` mixed into one. It's either/or. **Pick "ONE"**.

Comment: I agree with you. I think it's the `header();` that's failing because I took out that line and just added an `echo` and it prints out in the correct condition.

Comment: I just noticed something, the URL does change to the correct page but the page still shows the signon page. Any idea?

Comment: The code is working fine to me when set to redirect to google for one and yahoo for the other. So there is no fault in the code, you have something else missing when you put it into your entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you might need to use PHP's Output Buffer to fix that? When the script is parsed, having the output of the form in a function might be throwing it off, as the function will be parsed before the rest of the script is run.

Also, you should use `strcmp` for comparing strings, not the `==` sign. [strcmp vs ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/php-string-comparison-vs-strcmp)

Try using the output buffer functions and see if that fixes it. it's gonna look something like this:

```
function showForm($error=""){
ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Certificate Printing :: Login</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<Script>
$(function() {
  $("#user").focus();
});
</Script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="login" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="pwd">
    <h1>Log In</h1>
    <fieldset id="inputs">
        <input id="user" name="user" placeholder="Username" autofocus="" required="" type="text">   
        <input id="pass" name="pass" placeholder="Password" required="" type="password">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="radio" name="typereport" id="cbox" value="Clinical" checked="yes" /> Clinical 
        <input type="radio" name="typereport" id="cbox" value="Annual Education" /> Annual Education
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
    <div class="caption"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php   
return ob_get_flush();
}
```

[Output Buffers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) (php.net)

Comment: The signon page keeps refreshing

Comment: interesting. For me, that code works. I get a 404 because I don't have printCert.php on my machine

Comment: I'm curious, what is in the printExam.php file? is it possible that that file might be redirecting you back to the original file?

Comment: I just noticed something, the URL does change to the correct page but the page still shows the signon page. Any idea?

Comment: > For printCert.php and printCertHR.php, the very first line is:
`<?php require_once('printExam.php'); ?>`
that's gonna throw you into an "infinite loop" because All that logic is going to run again after the headers have been sent, so it'll check all the username and passwords again, so you'll be told you're not logged in, so you'll have to log back in, which will then redirect you to the appropriate page, which then will require the auth, which then will kick you back to printExam.php, which...  :)

Comment: Ahhhhh I see, well isn't require_once() just a one time sign on? What do you think is a better option? I am just trying to protect the two pages until a username/password has been authenticated.

Comment: `require_once` is during the life of the request. Everytime a new request is made (`header`) it can be included again. `require_once` is the PHP way of preventing Multiple Inclusion, if you're familiar with C/C++. As for how I would do it, I'd use Sessions. If the login works, set a session variable, (persists between requests), and check that after the authentication to see if they're logged in.

Comment: @SiKni8 To add to `Goldentoa11's` comment above; if you're going to use `sessions`, **Remember this:** You will need to have `session_start();` at the **top** of all or most pages.

Comment: @Goldentoa11 I updated my code, so I do not use the header(); rather display the webpages based on the selection. But now I see both HTML pages. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, because I was sanitizing, the ANNUAL EDUCATION was not checking correctly. I made it ANNUALEDUCATION and it worked just fine. Thanks to you both for the help.

Comment: @SiKni8 Glad to see you found your solution.

Answer (score 3):

The 'Location' *header* command in PHP should be followed with an `exit;`

Otherwise the code below is executed, ie any output is sent to the browser.

See the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) from the PHP header page:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```

Comment: Did not solve the error. The signon page keeps refreshing if the username/password is correct.

Comment: It keeps refreshing? So you're setting the header everytime the site is loaded.

Comment: I think it's the `header();` that's failing because I took out that line and just added an `echo` and it prints out in the correct condition.

Answer (score 2):

Location (or any other [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)) needs to be the first thing echoed by your script. Remove the blank lines in your script.

Comment: Right after IF statement, header is the first line.

Comment: There are blank lines before that.

Comment: Instead `header ("Location: printCert.php");` it should be `header("Location: printCert.php");`

Comment: I have another form which has space between `header` and `()` and that works just fine. I think it's the `header();` that's failing because I took out that line and just added an `echo` and it prints out in the correct condition.

Comment: Space doesn't matter, its the blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

You have contents being displayed before the header is being called (as for your comment to Rob W). The way to get around it is, put `ob_start();` at the top of your php code, and `ob_end_flush();` at the end of your code so the header can be called anywhere in between your code.

Comment: This is the right answer. Header cannot be used when anything else has been outputted before.

Comment: I think it's the `header();` that's failing because I took out that line and just added an `echo` and it prints out in the correct condition.

Answer (score 1):

After your `elseif ($report == "Annual Education") {` block, try `print_r($report)` - ensure it's what you are expecting...

```
if ($report == "Clinical") {
    header ("Location: printCert.php");
}
elseif ($report == "Annual Education") {
    header ("Location: printCertHR.php");
}
print_r($report);
```

Also, try monitoring FireBug's NET tab (or CHROME's)

Comment: I get this error now: `printcert.php
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/web/i/interfaithmedical.com/htdocs/checksite/printExam.php:45) in /home/web/i/interfaithmedical.com/htdocs/checksite/printExam.php on line 46`