# Why doesn't this php if-statement work as expected?

Tags: php, html

I'm passing the variable `$words` (a string containing the words "someText") to an if-statement. I'm testing whether the variable contains these words, and want to base any further logic of off that.

Weird thing is that the test returns `false` every time, even though the variable contains the words "someText"!

```
if ($words == "someText") {
  return "True " . $words;
} else {
  return "False " . $words;
}
```

The output value is always:

`False someText`

So the test equates to `false`, but the variable contains the words "someText"! Why is that?

---

*I should add that I'm using `return` instead of `echo` because my cms requires that, and I'm passing the value Older to the $words variable before running the code above.*

Comment: spell mistake may possible echo the value and check it ..

Comment: You're not checking if it *contains* `"Older"`, you're checking if it's the same string as `"Older"`. Where is the value coming from, and are you sure there isn't a newline at the end?

Comment: @Sundar, I did (the echo is the `. $olderIsTrue` part, if I made a spelling mistake, that word should look different right?

Comment: You are checking if the $olderIsTrue EQUALS "Older" not if it contains "Older"

Comment: have you checked the variable value outside.. declare in above if condition $olderIsTrue = "Older"; and check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/php-string-comparison-vs-strcmp

Comment: @Samuel `Trim` your `$olderIsTrue` variable then check

Comment: <?php
function sample($olderIsTrue){
if($olderIsTrue == "Older") {
  return "True " . $olderIsTrue;
} else {
  return "False " . $olderIsTrue;
}
}

$tmp = sample("Older");
echo $tmp;
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test, that the string contains the words, you need to use strstr function:

```
if (strstr($words, "someText") != false) {
  return "True " . $words;
} else {
  return "False " . $words;
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Comment: @robooneus No, look at the manual: "Returns the portion of string, or FALSE if needle is not found." This code works, I just tested it.

Comment: I will, can't yet, still have to wait a couple of mins according to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` operator.
30 characters limit.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some extra whitespace in the string that you don't notice in your output, but causes the comparison to fail. Try using `trim($olderIsTrue)` for the comparison. If that doesn't work, then for debugging purposes, try comparing `md5` hashes to see if the strings are in fact one and the same. Also, you might want to use the `===` operator, which is slightly faster than `==` and provides a strict comparison.