# How to get a div class to be displayed on certain pages using a template and php

Tags: php, html

I have a template for all my web pages but i want a div class not to be seen on certain pages. I use the URL to get the content out of a database with php so an example of my URL
= index.php?categorie=navigatie_bar&onderwerp=startpagina

I need a code to say get catagory from the url and if catagory is not navigation_bar

```
 echo '<div class"fb-comments"></div>';
```

can someone help ?

```
        <div id="container">
        <div id="pagina_text">

                    {{ CONTENT }}
                    </br>
                    <div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
                    </br></br>
                    <?php
                        if(strcmp($_GET['categorie'], "navigatie_bar") != 0)
                        {
                        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
                         }
                        ?>
        </div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
        </div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: I updated my answer. You make a lot of mistakes, then it is hard to find all the problems.. `<br />` not `</br>` and also you have some closing bracket in the `echo`, why?

Comment: well i was just trying some things and if i put the > in there it seems to take the div class the right way

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just basic PHP, a simple condition. But you seem to have also errors in our template. I would suggest running a w3c validator check, so you can see what you have wrong (wrongly nested tags, syntax mistakes etc..)
[W3C Validator Online](http://validator.w3.org/)

UPDATE:

```
  <div id="container">
        <div id="pagina_text">

                    {{ CONTENT }}
                    <br />
                    <div class="rw-ui-container"></div>
                    <br /><br/>
                    <?php
                        if(strcmp($_GET['categorie'], "navigatie_bar") != 0)
                        {
                        echo '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://alledaagsetips.nl"  data-numposts="10" data-colorscheme="light"></div>';
                         }
                        ?>
        </div> <!-- end pagina_text -->
        </div><!-- end container -->
```

Comment: Yeah i tought so too but there is one problem. If i put this code in my template.html he doesn't detect the div opening as a div only the closing so it closes an other div and my webpage is ruined.

Comment: There is a '=' missing after class

Comment: Sorry @MatthiasS, you are right, I just copied his code ;)

Comment: It still doesn't work. he only detects the closing div not the start div.... what can i do ?

Comment: Maybe you could paste more code,otherwise it's hard to find the problem. The code above definitely has to work

Comment: Maybe you have problems in your template, like wrong nested tags

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['category'] != 'navigation_bar'){
 echo '<div class="fb-comments"></div>'; 
}else{ //do this }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the URL variables via $_GET['name_of_parameter'].

```
if(strcmp($_GET['category'], "navigation_bar") != 0)
{
  echo '<div class="fb-comments"></div>'; 
}
```

In this case, only if `index.php?category=navigation_bar` the div will be echoed.

Take attention to your spelling, in your example you wrote **catagory** instead of **category**

EDIT:
You can do $_GET['category'] == 'navigation_bar', but for string comparisons it is sometimes safer to use the strcmp (string compare) function. 
See [String comparison using == vs. strcmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp)

Comment: still got the problem with the div. it only detects the closing tag and not the opening tag.....