# PHP running MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

So let me give you some information, i have a blog system which is backed to a database, the database holds the title of the articles. Now i have tried to create a "related news" feature, and it is rather basic, it just takes the title of the existing page and splits it up like so (Note that $row_object_title is just the title pulled from the database):

```
$row_object_title_lower = strtolower($row_object_title);
$keywords = explode(" ",$row_object_title_lower);
```

I then run it through my function:

```
exclude_conjuctions($keywords);
```

code for that function(looks for certain words and removes it from the array:

```
function exclude_conjuctions($array){
    global $keywords_new;

    $keywords_new = $array;
    $conjuctions = array("here","to","and","but","or","nor","for");

    $counter = count($keywords_new);
    foreach($conjuctions as $conjuction){
        for($i=0;$i <= $counter;$i++){
            if ($keywords_new[$i] == $conjuction){
                unset($keywords_new[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $keywords_new;
}
```

So now i will build my query to retreive all articles that have the keywords in the title:

```
$sql = '';
foreach ($keywords_new AS $keyword)
{
    if ($sql != '')
        $sql .= ' OR ';

    $sql .= "object_title LIKE '%$keyword%'";
}

$squery = 'SELECT object_title FROM example_table WHERE '.$sql;
```

NOW. It seems to be working okay, but there are times when it returns a title which does not have the same words as the current article, so i investigated it and it seems it picks up parts of the word and returns it, which is of course not what we want, if you are confused take a look at this image:

http://puu.sh/7UhhW.jpg

Note how i search for "dow" and those letters are found in both the current title and the retrieved titles. Of course i need it to only return related articles that have the full words in the title, not part of the words. What am i doing wrong guys? maybe my MySQL query needs to be changed? maybe there is a better solution? would love some help.

This is a problem as you can imagine.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: could you put echo $sql; before $squery(stuff) and show full query ?

Comment: @przeqpiciel Sure: SELECT object_title FROM webmanage_objects WHERE object_title LIKE '%messaging%' OR object_title LIKE '%service%' OR object_title LIKE '%whatsapp%' OR object_title LIKE '%goes%' OR object_title LIKE '%down%' OR object_title LIKE '%same%' OR object_title LIKE '%day%' OR object_title LIKE '%it%' OR object_title LIKE '%boasts%' OR object_title LIKE '%of%' OR object_title LIKE '%record%' OR object_title LIKE '%usage%' AND parentid=564 AND is_visible=1 AND archived=0 ORDER BY published_date DESC LIMIT 0,10

Comment: what if you this query put into phpmyadmin ? It is retur nwhat you want ? In my opinion you should put parenthesis somethink like this select fields from table ( you builded OR's query ) AND (parentid=564 AND is_visible=1 AND archived=0) ORDER BY ... other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `LIKE '% {$keyword} %'`

Also your query is vulnerable for SQL Injections.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

EDIT :  A better way to do this would be using a Regular Expression:

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]]{$keyword}[[:>:]]'
```

Instead of `LIKE...`

Comment: I already am aware of this,consultation on security is needed here. I will try your suggestion now.

Comment: This seems to have done the job, can you explain how this has fixed it please.

Comment: he put spaces before and after looking word it like search for word starting with this keyword or endind on this word - IMO :)

Comment: Your wild-cards and word are now separated with a space. This probably won't work with first & last words though.

Comment: maybe you should use regexp instead like statement ?

Comment: @przeqpiciel Edited with your advice.

Comment: can you please explain the difference, sorry im just trying to learn

Comment: The second one will also detect the first and last words of the title. Because the first doesn't start with a space in front of it and the last one doesn't end with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `===` operator instead of the `==` operator to compare strings.   A good reason why can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp)

Also, you are wrapping your query with `%` on each side.  That says to return all matches that CONTAIN those strings.  Thus 'Dow' is contained in 'Down' and would be returned.  You probably want to add a space around the `%`'s to only get matches that equal your keywords.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Yes, This would be more suited to be a comment, however i did make the change and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could you implement the "LIKE" search to include a preceding and succeeding space?  You would possibly need to have three conditions though to cater for words at the start and end of sentence:

```
$sql .= "object_title LIKE '% $keyword %' OR LIKE '$keyword %' OR LIKE '% $keyword'";
```

Comment: Please explain what difference this would make.

Comment: The three conditions allow for $keyword to appear at the start, end or midway through a sentence.  So as per your example where: $keyword = "dow"  '% $keyword %' matches 'sometext dow some more text', '$keyword %' matches 'dow sometext' and '% $keyword' matches 'some text dow'