# how to check if variable is equal to another exact variable including upper and lower case

Tags: php, variables

So ive searched around and cant find the answer what im trying to do is find out if a variable is equal to another variable in exact characters.

```
<?php
$a = 'aBcD';
$b = 'abcd';
if($a == $b){
echo 'yep';
} else {
echo 'nope';
}
//variables above are not equal to each other
?>
```

aBcD and abcd are not equal but no matter what i try it always comes up as true. Im sure theres an easy way to find this out but i cant seem to find it. can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: it says `nope`, if you have `yep` make sure you use double equal sign `==` in condition statement.

Comment: You'll find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp

Comment: When I run your code, I get 'nope', which is what I was expecting.

Comment: I keep getting yep. could it be because im getting it straight from the db. should i make it a variable before comparing?

Comment: Found the issue it was down to collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare two case-insensitive strings, transform both using `strtolower`.

```
if (strtolower($a) === strtolower($b)) {
    // string are equal
}
```

See that I used `===` to avoid situation when `1 == '1a'` - I find two identical case-insensitive strings.

Comment: hey, ill explain it abit more and what its for. its basically checking against the database for XBOX gamertags and you know you can have similar lookin GT for exmaple. ThePro and thepro. They are 2 different users but my script sees them both as the same person. so if a user wants to add their GT their and it has the same charascters as somone else they cant

Comment: @user3833066: no problem, I understood your question. Just use what I wrote above, ideally with `===`, because in PHP `1 == '1a'`, but `1 !== '1'`.

Comment: its still doing the same as before ):

Comment: @user3833066: no, it works. Maybe you implemented it bad, but I don't know what you're doing with it. It works, don;t worry. Now it's up to you :-)

Comment: the issue was down to collation

Answer (score 1):

`==` is case sensitive.
Check for [strcasecmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

```
var_dump(strcasecmp('aBcD', 'abcd') == 0); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php
    $a = 'aBcD';
    $b = 'abcd';
    if(strtolower($a) == strtolower($b)){
    echo 'yep';
    } else {
    echo 'nope';
    }
    //variables above are not equal to each other
?>
```

Use  strtolower function to convert all string to lower and then check condition.

Comment: than what do you want, can you elaborate it exactly ?