# Need exact reason for this logically condition failed

Tags: php, if-statement

Why below code is printing the "here", it should be "there"

```
$a = "171E-10314";
if($a == '0')
{
echo "here";
}
else
{
echo "there";   
}
```

Comment: it's working as expected `here`.

Comment: according to the code, $a does not equal zero - it equals some strange string

Comment: any reason why it 171E-10314 is equal to 0 so printing here

Comment: @RamRaider the OPs issue is happening here - https://3v4l.org/Iv1mi

Comment: ok - that is kinda weird!

Comment: "Even if you are comparing strings to strings, PHP will implicitly cast them to floats and do a numerical comparison if they appear numerical." - from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP automatically parses anything that's a number or an integer inside a string to an integer. `"171E-10314"` is another way of telling PHP to calculate `171 * 10 ^ -10314`, which equates to (almost) `0`. So when you do `$a == '0'`, the `'0'` will equate to `0` according to PHP, and it returns `true`.

If you want to compare strings, use the [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function or use the strict comparator `===`.

Answer (score 1):

when you use the == comparison, PHP tries to cast to different data types to check for a match like that

in your case:

- '0' becomes 0
- "171E-10314" is still mathematically almost 0 but I think PHP just rounds it to 0 due to the resolution of float.

check this link for a visual representation:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=171E-10314

Answer (score 0):

Use `=== /*(this is for the 30 character)*/`

Comment: I updated code to use ===, but any reason why 171E-10314 is equal to 0

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp

Answer (score 0):

As per the answers given I tried to convert the string into numerical:

```
$a = "171E-10314" + 0;
print $a;
```

And I got output as 0.

Thats why it is printing here.