# How to check whether the two strings' contents are the same?

Tags: php

For example `str1 = "hello world"`,`str2 = "hello wordl"`,they have the same length,but are not same

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use levenshtein.

```
If (levenshtein($str1,$str2)===0){ // identical}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. you can use [strcmp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) for string comparison.

Comment: isn't it compares only the length of two strings?