# Why var_dump return true with different comparison of md5 hash?

Tags: php

I wonder why this code return true instead of false

```
var_dump(md5('240610708') == md5('QNKCDZO'));
```

Thanks in advance, any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Because `0 == 0`

Comment: The second answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var_dump(md5('240610708') === md5('QNKCDZO'));
```

Comment: Is it verified?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with your values, and again using the same value for both MD5 expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks, like these md5 hashes, which starts from '0e', are parsed by PHP as a decimal numbers with exponent (see `var_dump(100 == "1e2"); // 100 == 100 -> true` from [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)).

That is why they are interpreted as equals. To avoid this, must use strict comparison.

**Update:**

And `strcmp` gives the correct result, too. If I understand correctly, because there is no conversions in case of `strcmp`.

Comment: You can also use `strcmp()`