# PHP If statements with SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project where a user will login and it only shows records if the `rep` column is their `name`. I know there's a ton of ways to do this but the easiest way for me is to use If statements with sessions

```
if($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'Rep') {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep='".$_SESSION['name']."' ";

} elseif ($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'Manager')  {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE Manager='".$_SESSION['name']."' ";

} elseif ($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'Regional')  {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE Region='".$_SESSION['regional']."' ";

} elseif ($_SESSION['account_type'] == 'Other')  {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` ";

} else {
    echo 'no records found';
}
```

If your account type is a `rep`, show just records with your name. If your account type is `manager`, show records where the manager record has your name, etc etc.

For some reason, I'm not getting any records back at all; its blank.

If I change it to just:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep='".$_SESSION['name']."' ";
```

I get records back where it has the users name in the rep column; which is great but i need the if statements to work.

Any ideas?

*UPDATE*

Syntax error - thanks!

Comment: no errors at all just blank only?

Comment: did you started session on top of the page ?

Comment: blank page means error in  somewhere in your code

Comment: I have noticed that in your elseif where you are querying Regional, your session variable is $_SESSION['regional'] instead of $_SESSION['name'], whereas you are referring to only later throughout. Is it intentional?

Comment: yes i started the session at the top. It works when i just use $sql = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE rep='".$_SESSION['name']."' ";  so the name session is there.

Comment: Please post the correct answer and accept it so that this question is closed properly.

Comment: Are you still having this problem ? Please close this ticket properly if it's solved

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` or `strcmp` function.
You shouldn't use `==` for `String` comparison.

Try `if($_SESSION['account_type'] === 'Rep')`
and so on...

Comment: it should be in comment area  and if any if condition not meet at least it should echo the else part . but he telling that he getting blank page . so somewhere in his code is error

Comment: you're right, i found there error (Home Simpson DOH!)

Comment: I don know why you said this but please visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm

mysql where clause has operator like == or === it only allow = for equal condition

Comment: @hamed Do you have an explanation or reference for why you shouldn't use `==` for String comparison?

Comment: @topher sure, `==` is a loose comparison, while `===` is not, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8494892/5559741