# check two identical str with str_replace

Tags: php, string, compare

```
$first = 'test - yes';
$second = 'yes';
$third = str_replace("test -", "", $first);

if ($second == $third) {
    echo 'yee';
    echo '<br>';
}
echo $first;
echo '<br>';
echo $second;
echo '<br>';
echo $third;
```

I have 3 variables. First variable has str - test - yes, second - yes and third is replaced with first with removed "test -"

So when i broughted all 3 variables i had this result "test - yes;
yes;
yes;" Second and third variable are the same, and when i check if ($second == $third) {
    echo 'yee'; } it doesnt echo it; Why

Comment: You're missing a space at the end  of `"test -"` use `"test - "`

Comment: You didn't remove the space after `-`.

Comment: When you print strings to visually compare them, use var_dump as it shows the character count and the string enclosed in `""`

Answer (score 1):

> $first = 'test - yes';
>      $second = 'yes';
>      $third = str_replace("test -", "", $first);

After this `$second` and `$third` are not exactly equal. I mean the `$third` variable contains an extra space before `yes`.

Another thing is you are not comparing strings this way. You can compare strings by either `===` or `strcmp($second,$third)==0`. Check [String comparison using == vs. strcmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp) stackoverflow answer for more details on this.