# Returning data from user in Concrete5 doesn't evaluate as true when tested

Tags: php, string, concrete5

I am storing data from a form to user data in Concrete5.

I am pulling the user data successfully:

```
$u = new User();
$ui = UserInfo::getByID($u->getUserID());
$testtype = $ui->getAttribute('TestType','display');
```

This return what I expect.  But when I try to evaluate it using...

```
} else if ($testtype == "English Adult Male") {
```

...it doesn't trigger.

I echo the output I am pulling, and notice the html put a `<br>` after the echo of the variable.  I have tried to pass the output through `trim` but the same comes out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$testtype` probably doesn't have the value you think it does. What does `var_dump($testtype);` show?

Comment: It's returning `string(23) "English Adult Male
"`.  The second quote is on a new line.  I am testing for this string also.

Comment: According to the code you posted the if statement is correctly not triggering because you are not testing for that value.

Comment: That was an example.  I am testing for that value also.  `} else if ($testtype == "English Adult Male") {`.  Adjusted question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you using some framework?

Comment: The data is being stored in Concrete5 user attributes.

Answer (score 1):

use `===` instead of `==` for comparison in general as a good practice. More read on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333353/string-comparison-using-vs-strcmp)

Change your code this way that you have `$case` with string in it and do `var_dump` of both `$case` and `$testtype`

```
<?php

$testtype = "English Adult Male ";
$case = "English Adult Male ";
var_dump($testtype);
var_dump($case);

if ($testtype === "whatever") {
    echo "IF!";

} else if ($testtype === $case) {
    echo "ELSE IF!";
}
```

the code above generates output:

```
string(19) "English Adult Male "
string(19) "English Adult Male "
ELSE IF!
```

Note

> string(**19**) not string(**23**)

you have 23 in your var dump that is more than number of character in the string `"English Adult Male "` that leads me to the conclusion that you have a multibyte character encoding but probably you are testing with your string that is not multibyte but singlebyte and its 19 bytes string vs 23 bytes string.

you can convert your `$testtype` by [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

and its [supported encodings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php)

also [mb_detect_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) may be handy to detect encoding of `$testtype`;

Comment: Both the test and the variable are returning an ASCII type.  There are, I assume, hidden/encoding characters.  I assume the 2 extra would be for `\n` or `\r` but trim should have taken care of that, right?

Comment: is both `var_dump()` = string(**23**) "English Adult Male "? Yes [trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) should remove `\r` and `\n` for new lines, as well as spaces. You may also use [mb_strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) to make case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Trim still returns a 23 length.  Maybe this is a concrete5 specific thing.  I will check on their forums!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the line

```
$testtype = $ui->getAttribute('TestType','display');
```

By changing this to:

```
$testtype = $ui->getAttribute('TestType');
```

Then setting the conditional to `==`, because `===` wouldn't work, the result was as desired.

Hope this helps someone!